# linux vim latex-suite compile oddity

Tags: vim, latex-suite

Running linux, when I compile a latex document from within vim with the latex-suite installed, I am (needlessly) prompted to hit ENTER.  That is, when I type `\ll` to compile, the screen appears to drop out of vim to the command prompt which reads:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Hitting ENTER returns me to vim with my document successfully compiled, however I'd prefer not to have to hit ENTER here (I don't have this same problem running from a Mac).

My .tex file reads as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{This is the title}
\author{The Author}
\date{September 2013}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

From within vim, I give the following command:

```
:echo g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat
```

and receive

```
pdf
```

I give the following command:

```
:echo g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf
```

and receive

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode $* >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

From the bash prompt I can type

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode HelloWorld.tex >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

and pdflatex compiles my document without requesting that I hit ENTER. Any help to not have to hit ENTER at the command prompt would be appreciated.

Comment: The prompt is coming from vim. not pdflatex

Comment: Hmm.  So is there a command or variable I can set in my .vimrc to disable the ENTER-request?

Answer (score 0):

You can remap the `\ll` or create a new mapping, for example `\ls` for silent compiling:

```
map <leader>ls :silent call Tex_RunLaTeX()<cr>
```

The key here is the `silent` command, which prevents vim from asking you to hit Enter. However, you won't see any output from this.